# linux to compile multiple java file

Tags: linux, shell, javac

here is my directory structure.

/user/a
/user/b
/user/b

inside folder a,b,c there is a file person.java (it is the Same file, just a one line modification.

now, on my shell, im on my /user/ directory and i try to do

```
   javac */person.java
```

the shell returns the following error,

person.java:14: duplicate class: person

Is there anything to resolve this?

Comment: Are the classes exactly the same, with the same package definition on top?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem here might be, that javac tries to compile everything in one go, which naturally results in duplicated class definitions.

A simple way to resolve this would be

`find . -name '*.java' -exec javac {} \;`

**Edit:**

Or to be more precise `find . -name 'person.java' -maxdepth 2 -exec javac {} \;`

Comment: Here you compile all the file ending in .java, not only the person.java files. Also you don't restrict to one level of subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the small shell script:

```
for f in */person.java; do
  javac $file
done
```

First line find all the files person.java in a sub-directory, second line compile the file.

Comment: in a shell, is there a well to type the above for loop "in" the console,

so i dont have to create a separate .sh file?

Comment: Yes, just type it as you see it here, or optionally put it all on one line: for f in */person.java; do javac $file; done